# Meteor: how can I avoid checking for the existence of a variable or property everywhere?

Tags: javascript, exception, meteor

When programming in Meteor I often find myself having to sprinkle typechecks or existence checks a bunch when writing Template helpers (at least under a couple very common conditions).

- A helper for one template depends on a collection loaded by a different template
- Any time a template helper operates on a piece of the DOM that another template is responsible for rendering into existence

For example (in the first case):

```
Template.example.rendered
    rev1 = getRev(revId1)
    revText1 = html2plain(rev1.text)
```

where getRev is doing an operation on the Revisions collection that may or may not be loaded by the time the example template is **first** rendered. So rev1.text will sometimes throw an exception because getRev ends up returning null or undefined if called before Revisions is loaded.

I then end up having to check a ton of variables/objects throughout my code for existence before using any of their properties just to be safe.

- I could imagine using a router to not render my example template until after a different collection is ready (but for nested templates, and Session variable changes this doesn't work so hot).
- I could imaging wrapping the helper code in a if (isCollectionReady) which might help but doesn't seem best practice.

The question is: Is there a canonical or best practice way to, identify these situations, code for them, or avoid this altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is designed such that its templates are reactive, so that in most cases you shouldn't need to do DOM manipulations on them. As the underlying data changes, the templates automatically rerender so that they're always showing the latest data. Take a look at the examples in the Meteor docs: they don't use any DOM manipulation code. The templates put the data into the right places, and that's all they need.

In my experience there are two common reasons to need to put code into `rendered`:

1. You're loading a widget that needs to be initialized after the template is rendered and ready, like a `<select>` replacement.
2. You're doing animations. (In this case, I usually tell my template to put everything in its proper place but with a CSS class that hides the elements, and then all `rendered` does is animate the reveals.)

It's usually fine for a template to render before its subscription has loaded; at worst, the template will just render blank and then rerender as the data streams in. Also remember that you can `subscribe` from client-side code other than a template helper, for example `Meteor.startup` on the client side. Finally don't forget about the `created` helper; if you really want to wait until a template is loaded before subscribing, that would be a better place to subscribe than `rendered`, as it gets called sooner.

What DOM manipulations are you doing and why? Assuming you're not using widgets or animations, chances are that you can achieve what you want by using templates on their own without any additional manipulation code.

Comment: Avoiding the DOM stuff I mostly get. The stickier stuff for me is interfacing with the local collection or code that runs on both client and server that operates on a collection. My primary example might do a RevCollection.findOne({title: titleOf}) and assign that to the variable 'rev1'. It seems to me that everytime I do this I either have to wrap all following code in a check for rev1's existence, or check for the existence of any property of rev1 ...e.g. rev1.text before I actually use it or there is a very real risk of an exception (all of this because the collection may not have loaded)

Comment: In template helpers and other code yes, you pretty much always need to do a quick check. Something like `return if Session.equals('rev1', null);` as the first line of any function. For templates though you shouldn't need to bother. Wrap the whole template inside `{{#if this}}` (assuming the template is called with the `rev1` session variable as its context) and the template won't render if `rev1` is null.